# How to convert Plist data to JSON format?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am using plist to save my data locally when network connection is not available, and when network is available i want to sync my locally saved data to the web server.In this process i want to convert my plist data to JSON data and post that data to web server. Can any one help me one this?

Comment: EitherDictOrArray (according to the top level of you data) can be used to read from/converted into plist data ((with some limitations on object classes)). EitherDictOrArray can be read from/converted into JSON (with some limitations on object classes). What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

You can access data from plist in dictionary format thenceforth serialize it to get json string.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourPlistName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary* dict= [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data
                                                     mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                               format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                     errorDescription:NULL];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict 
                                    options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error]; 
NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

-----SWIFT 3-----

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"yourPlistName", withExtension: "plist") {
do {
 let data = try Data(contentsOf:url)
 let dict = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as! [String:Any]
  let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict , options: .prettyPrinted)
   // jsondata  your required data
   } catch {
  print(error)
 }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is in Swift and the author tagged the question as Objective-C

Comment: Still upvoting this answer, because other answers use deprecated methods `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` / `initWithContentsOfFile`. This one is easy to rewrite to Objective-C

Comment: Thanks @mag_zbc . I have updated ans in objective -c . I have not tested it yet as I am away from my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *plistDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below

```
NSString * plistPath = @“data.plist”;
NSMutableDictionary *plistData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: plistPath];
NSError * err;
NSString * jsonStr = nil;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization  dataWithJSONObject:plistData options:0 error:&err];
jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

My plist was an NSArray, not an NSDictionary, so I had to do this:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *menuArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSError *err;
NSString *jsonStr = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization  dataWithJSONObject:menuArray options:0 error:&err];
jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```